# AST is conservative over ZF

Tags: logic, set-theory

So this statement that AST is conservative over ZF is an exercise in Ralf Schindler's book, which I need to prove, but I am having trouble with it.

So the formulation of AST(Ackerman's Set Theory) which I will be using, is the following: Our language is $\mathcal{L}_\epsilon$ together with a constant symbol $\dot{v}$. And the axioms are **Extensionality**, **Foundation**, **Comprehension**(the same old ZF one), an axiom saying $\dot{v}$ is both transitive and supertransitive and one reflection axiom for each formula $\varphi(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ **of** $\mathcal{L}_\epsilon$ stating that:
$$\forall v_1\in\dot{v}\dots \forall v_n\in\dot{v} (\varphi^{\dot{v}} \leftrightarrow \varphi)$$

So in a previous exercise I had proven that AST $\vdash$ ZF. So by reflection, we have that $\dot{v} \models $ ZF. Also since AST $\vdash$ ZF, by using the coding in Devlin's book for example, we can see that the satisfaction relation for sets can be constructed in AST, thus AST proves Con(ZF), since $\dot{v}$ is just another set in AST's universe.

This is my problem.  How can AST be conservative over ZF and also in the mean time prove Con(ZF)?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this formulation of AST?

Comment: @user76284, this formulation can be found at the end of the problem section of chapter 2 of Schindler's "Set theory exploring independence and truth". But, other than the formulation and the problem, there isn't much more stated about AST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer is **incorrect**. $\omega$-consistency does **not** say "If you prove $P(n)$ for each standard $n$, then you prove $\forall n(P(n))$." That would be $\omega$-**completeness**.

Rather, $\omega$-consistency says "If you prove $\exists x\neg P(x)$, then you must **not** prove $P(n)$ for each standard $n$." And in particular, both $AST$ and the theory $T$ introduced in that answer **are** $\omega$-consistent, at least assuming $ZFC$ is to begin with.

Getting back to the main question, it may help to drop $AST$ and consider the simpler fact about $ZFC$ alone, which is itself provable in ZFC:

> $(*)\quad$ For every $M\models ZFC$ there is some structure $A\in M$ such that $A\models ZFC$ ... even if $M\models\neg Con(ZFC)$.

The key point is that "$A\models ZFC$" is interpreted in *reality*; we may not have $M\models(A\models ZFC)$.

**This also explains why the OP's reflection argument breaks down - it's exactly the same reason.**

Here's how to prove $(*)$ in ZFC:

- If $ZFC$ is inconsistent then $(*)$ is vacuously true.
- Suppose $ZFC$ is consistent. Let $M\models ZFC$. If $M\models Con(ZFC)$ then since $ZFC$ proves the completeness theorem we're done.
- So suppose $M\models \neg Con(ZFC)$. Let $n\in\omega^M$ be *what $M$ thinks is* the largest number such that there is no proof of a contradiction from the first $n$ axioms of $ZFC$. If we can conclude that $n$ is nonstandard, we'll be done: by completeness in $M$, any model $A$ of the first $n-1$ axioms of $ZFC$ in the sense of $M$ will in reality be a model of $ZFC$, even if $M$ doesn't think so.

Now here's the cute bit: we **internalize** the reflection principle. Looking at the usual argument we see in fact that **ZFC proves** "ZFC proves every finite subtheory of ZFC."  (Note the crucial nested "proves" here.) This means we can next say...

- Since $M\models ZFC$, for each standard $k$ we have $M\models$ "The first $k$ axioms of $ZFC$ are consistent." So $n$ is nonstandard and we're done.

Comment: So, the argument proposed by Hanul, actually shows that AST, is not $\omega$-complete, instead of $\omega$-inconsistent, right?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Yes - and that's not surprising: Godel's theorem says that for appropriate theories, $\omega$-completeness implies inconsistency!

Comment: That theorem has a certain unique "Wow!" factor!

Comment: "This also explains why the OP's reflection argument breaks down - it's exactly the same reason.", I don't understand this part. Because I only use the reflection axiom for sentences which are axioms of ZF to show that $\dot{v}$ satisfies them.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri My point is that you try to go from "For each $\varphi\in ZFC$, $AST\vdash v\models \varphi$" to "$AST\vdash v\models ZFC$." The former is true, the latter isn't. And the fact that you can't in fact do this is exactly why the reflection argument above *doesn't* result in a contradiction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber But what if we consider an $M\models$ ZFC with the least rank? Doesn't the theorem lead to a contradiction, since the structure $A \in M$ must have a lower rank?

Comment: @user123 Nope - in this case the structure $A\in M$ will be ill-founded and this prevents rank considerations from being useful. In particular, in this case $A$'s well-founded part('s height) will be shorter than $height(M)$, but that's OK - the shortest well-founded part of an ill-founded model is just $\omega$ (or if you demand $\omega$-model-ness, it's $\omega_1^{CK}$).

Comment: This becomes clearer if you think about the details of how $A$ is built inside $M$. Within $M$, we observe (by $\omega$-model-ness of $M$) that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent. This means that we can run the Henkinization construction inside $M$. We get a "really rich" (= having the witness property) complete consistent extension $\mathsf{ZFC}\subset T\in M$, and then let $A$ be the term model of this $T$. But why should $A$ so constructed be well-founded - or indeed, nice in *any* sense other than being an element of $M$ and satisfying $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry I don't see why the ill-foundedness of $A$ matters. What is wrong with the following argument? Let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that there is some set $M$ of rank $\alpha$ such that there is some $R\subset M \times M$ with $(M, R) \models $ ZFC. Fix such $M$. Then the theorem implies that there is an $A \in M$ with $(A, \in^A) \models$ ZFC where $\in^A \subset A \times A$. But $A$ has rank $<\alpha$.

Comment: @user123 This should be a separate question rather than a comment, but short version: your last sentence is a non sequitur. (For starters, note that your $\alpha$ is just $\omega+1$ since by downward Lowenheim-Skolem $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a model with underlying set $\omega$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've asked the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855743/on-every-model-of-zfc-has-an-element-that-is-a-model-of-zfc. Any more help will be really appreciated!

Comment: @user123 Eric beat me to it, his answer is exactly right.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see now. Thanks! I also added a comment to his answer, do you think my complaint makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

*(I had deleted this answer as it does not answer the question. I undeleted it for the context of the comments in Noah Schweber's answer, with some modifications.)*

<del>I checked [Reinhardt's original article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484370900112), and I found that what he proved is the following statement:</del>

> <del>**Theorem** (Reinhardt, Results 0.2.) If $\phi$ is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZF}$, then $\mathsf{AST}$ proves $\phi^{\dot{v}}$. Moreover, the converse also holds.</del>

<del>Hence I think Schindler states the exercise problem somewhat misleadingly.</del>

I was not correct at that point. OP's comment on the reflection argument seems to work.

I reached an unexpected conclusion: $\mathsf{AST}$ is not <del>$\omega$-consistent</del>$\omega$-complete by the following argument: we may identify formulas to natural numbers by coding. We know that $\mathsf{AST}\vdash \phi\in\ulcorner\mathsf{ZF}\urcorner\to c\models \phi$ for each 'standard' $\phi$. 
If $\mathsf{AST}$ is $\omega$-complete, then we have $\mathsf{AST}\vdash \forall\phi:\phi\in\ulcorner\mathsf{ZF}\urcorner\to c\models \phi$ for each 'standard' $\phi$. This means $\mathsf{AST}\vdash \dot{v}\models\mathsf{ZF}$. 
However, we know that $\mathsf{AST}$ and $\mathsf{ZF}$ are equiconsistent.

Here is another example of an extension of $\mathsf{ZF}$ that is not $\omega$-complete (maybe due to Feferman.) Consider the language $\langle \in,c\rangle$, where $c$ is a constant symbol. Let $T$ be the theory given by the following axioms: the usual axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$, the statement that $c$ is a transitive set, and $\phi^c$ for all axioms $\phi$ of $\mathsf{ZF}$.
By the similar argument for $\mathsf{AST}$, $T$ is $\omega$-incomplete.

Comment: The converse is the troublesome part. As Con(ZF) is a sentence in the language $\mathcal{L}_\epsilon$, then it reflects to $\dot{v}$, so we have Con(ZF)$^\dot{v}$. So, how can this be?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri AST is not strong enough to prove there is a truth predicate over $\dot{v}$. Hence the presence of $\dot{v}$ does not result in Con(ZF).

Comment: I don't understand. Since AST proves $\varphi^\dot{v}$ for each axiom $\varphi$ of ZF, then by reflection, it proves $\varphi$ as well. So AST proves ZF, and again we can code the truth predicate for sets, just like we do in ZF.

Comment: (I think there are relevant answers on Mathoverflow or this site. But I don't know how to find it.)

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but since this stuff is a little bit confusing for me, I have a question. When you say AST is equiconsistent with ZF, you mean they are equiconsistent over ZFC, right? Since for going from Con(ZF) to Con(AST) I think we do need to use compactness and the reflection theorem, no?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Yes, I assume ZF(C) as a metatheory.

Comment: "If $\mathsf{AST}$ is $\omega$-consistent, then we have $\mathsf{AST}\vdash \forall\phi:\phi\in\ulcorner\mathsf{ZF}\urcorner\to c\models \phi$ for each 'standard' $\phi$." What? No, that's not right at all. That's $\omega$-*completeness*.

Comment: Your argument about $T$ breaks down for the same reason.

Comment: In fact, every model of $ZFC$ has an expansion to $T$ by naming a single constant - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/51786/8133) (or my answer).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for correcting me. I did not know the correct meaning of $\omega$-consistency and $\omega$-completeness. (I had searched it but I confused, which is my fault.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber As far as I understand, my conclusion on $\omega$-incompleteness ($T\vdash \phi(n)$ for all $n$ does not necessarily imply $T\vdash \forall x\in\omega \phi(x)$) is correct, but it does not hit the main paradox in the OP. I wonder my understanding is correct.