# On "Every model of ZFC has an element that is a model of ZFC"

Tags: set-theory

There is a theorem saying that every model of ZFC has an element that is a model of ZFC (see Joel Hamkins's post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51754/clearing-misconceptions-defining-is-a-model-of-zfc-in-zfc/51786#51786 and Noah Schweber's answer here [AST is conservative over ZF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633532/ast-is-conservative-over-zf?rq=1)).

My question is why the theorem does not lead to a contradiction by the following argument (with the assumption that ZFC is consistent)?

Let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that there is a set $M$ of rank $\alpha$ such that $\langle M, \in^M \rangle \models$ ZFC with $\in^M \subseteq M \times M$. Fix such $M$. Then the theorem implies that there is some $A \in M$ such that $\langle A, \in^A\rangle \models $ ZFC for some $\in^A \subseteq A \times A$. But A has rank $< \alpha$.

Answer (score 5):

The "model of ZFC in $M$" that exists is represented by some element $A\in M$ together with a relation ${\in^A}\in M$, but this model is not literally the set $A$ with that relation; instead it is the set $B=\{a:a\in^M A\}$ together with the relation ${\in^B}=\{\langle a,b\rangle:M\models a\in^A b\}$.  This set $B$ can have the same rank as $M$, since it need not be an element of $M$.

(Indeed, it is easy to see that $\alpha=\omega$ since $M$ can be taken to have underlying set any countable set, say $M=\omega$.  Then $A$ will be a finite ordinal, but in the structure $\langle M,\in^M\rangle$ it will represent an infinite set.)

Comment: I see, thanks. But isn't this "theorem" a bit of abusing the terminology? When we say a structure models ZFC, don't we mean that the structure has a domain $D$ and an interpretation $I$ of $\in$ which is a subset of $D \times D$?

Comment: If your models aren't transitive, then you virtually never care about what the elements of your model literally are as sets, since you could replace them by any other sets and get an isomorphic structure.  So it is completely uninteresting to talk about a model containing another model as an element in that literal sense.  It would be like asking whether a group contains a model of ZFC as an element; sure, it could, but this is completely irrelevant to the group structure.